# How to get a substring up to "\r\n\r\n"

Tags: c, string, strstr

I have the following string:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 11:53:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: text/html

��(�ͱ���I�O����H�����ч��
                          �4�@��AQ������t
```

I want to extract up to the `"\r\n\r\n"`, discarding the binary data. I.e. :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 11:53:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: text/html
```

How to do this in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could easily be done by simple finding the first two sequential linebreaks, since this terminates the header, and then copy everything upto that point to a separate buffer:

```
// Find the end of the header, which is terminated
// by two line breaks
char* end = strstr(header, "\r\n\r\n");
char* buffer = 0;
if (end) {
    // Allocate memory to hold the entire header
    buffer = malloc((end - header) + 1);
    if (buffer) {
        // Copy header to buffer
        memcpy(buffer, header, end - header);
        // NULL terminate the buffer
        buffer[end - header] = 0;
        // Do something with the buffer here
    
        // Don't forget to release the allocated memory
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be alloc((end - header) + 1) so that the 0x00 is also stored in valid allocated memory?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) function.

But be aware that there exist good C libraries for HTTP client (like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) and for HTTP server (like [onion](http://www.ohloh.net/p/onionhttp)) sides. And that [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) is complex in its details.

Comment: I tried strstr, but it returns a pointer to the binary data! `strstr(buf,"\r\n\r\n")` - how to overcome this?

Comment: Of course it does, you'll need to manipulate everything UP TO the pointer returned by strstr (see @Krister Andersson post below)